# Why change input interval value on mysql?

Tags: mysql

I want create event that execute every monday 00:00:00.
I created event but don't work. In my Opinion, reason is interval value.

I use EVERY 1 WEEK option but mysql display 7 interval value. Is it right reason? If yes why don't input correct value?

**This is my create query**

```
CREATE EVENT IF NOT EXISTS clear_temp_week_news_count
    ON SCHEDULE every 1 week starts CURRENT_DATE + INTERVAL 7 - WEEKDAY(CURRENT_DATE) DAY
    on completion preserve enable    
    DO
    delete from temp_week_news_count;
```

**This is result when use "show events;"**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e5Nbz.png)

I did check db status on with "SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'event%';"

Comment: I cannot reproduce your issue locally or https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=4fdf12f738ecd00bf024c40e546a6820 - All I can suggest is you drop and create.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I know,  query don't have runtime error. 
I want know, why last_exectued_time write UTC. My DB timezone is '+9:00'.
That column always wirte basis on UTC?